# How to define Global scope of variable in Twig

Tags: global-variables, twig

How do we declare a variable as global in Twig?

The variable is going to be inside multiple blocks in twig template, and every block should be able to use that changed variable.

I have tried doing that, but it retains the value of the variable in which it is declared.

Comment: If you are using `Symfony2`, read the following: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html

Comment: @DaniSancas I am not using Symfony2. I need to use twig in FoxyCart custom templates. And the data structure they have is a bit complex to turn into needed html output.

Comment: So sad :( The only hint I have are `includes with parameters`. If doesn't fit you I'm sorry, I have nothing more: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

Comment: Thanks @DaniSancas for your help :-) Anyways I will figure out some other way to complete the task ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a global variable in twig, call [`addGlobal()`](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Environment.php#L1017) on your `\Twig_Environment` instance. I'm unfamiliar with FoxyCart and its twig integration, so I cannot help you with the details.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using Drupal 8**, then you can add variables into preprocess_pages